# Django manage.py test can't see urls.py, although runserver can

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I got a django project, with the following directory structure:

```
BaseDir
| manage.py
| configDir
 \
  | settings.py , urls.py, wsgi.py
|mainApp
 \ 
  |urls.py , views, models etc.
  | tests
  \
   |urlTest.py
```

(In case the above is not clear, there's a django config dir and a mainApp dir, the mainApp has it's own urls.py and the tests dir, all directories are python modules with an **init**.py)

if I run

```
manage.py runserver
```

I get the expected application running as it should on the django server.

however  running

```
manage.py test
```

i get the following

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

The test is the following:

```
[...]
class TestSth(BaseTest):
def setUp(self):
    [some db setup such as users etc]

def test_get(self):
    pprint.pprint(reverse('index'))
```

config/urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^mainApp/', include('mainApp.urls')),
]
```

mainApp/urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
app_name = 'app'

urlpatterns = [
    #/app/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    [...]
```

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong? This doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared an app_name in mainApp/urls.py, so you need to use that in the reverse call:

```
pprint.pprint(reverse('app:index'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NoReverseMatch` exception is raised by `django.urls` when a matching URL in your URLconf cannot be identified based on the parameters supplied.

You should also pass the `urlConf` parameter to the `reverse` function

`reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)`

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#module-django.urls):

> The urlconf argument is the URLconf module containing the URL patterns
>   to use for reversing. By default, the root URLconf for the current
>   thread is used.